# Way to setup settings_staging, settings_production and settings_local files in django

Tags: python, django

I have three systems for my django project for which i need three different settings file for each respective system i.e local,staging and production.

After doing some research I though of a way i.e to set an environmental variable corresponding to the system. For local i am setting env variable as 'localserver', for staging server i am setting 'staging' and so on for production.

**Settings.py**

```
server_environment = os.environ.get('XYZ_ENV')

if server_environment == 'staging':
    try:
        from rest_apis.settings_staging import *
    except ImportError:
        pass
elif server_environment == 'production':
    try:
        from settings_production import *
    except ImportError:
        pass
elif server_environment == 'localserver':
    try:
        from settings_local import *
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

**local.py**

```
from rest_apis.settings import *
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'xyz',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://myuser:mypassword@127.0.0.1:5672//'
```

Same type of config for different systems.
Here what is happening, inspite of cross verifying that it goes to correct if-else block, it doesn't apply the proper settings. It always connect to DB Host specify in Settings.py file.

Also if i stop my instance (i have private IP, so on restart IP doesn't change) and I start again, then it again create the same issue.

I did stackoverflow for it and tried various solutions for it but none of them helped. What am i doing wrong ? Also, what is the correct way for this type of situation. 
I don't want to make hardcore changes to the system by logging(ssh) into each and every system.

Comment: What do you mean *"DB Host specify in Settings.py file"*? Do you still have all of the old settings in the base `settings.py` *after* that conditional?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes i do have old settings. But ideally it should override the settigns.py file right ?

Comment: Anything in the script *after* those `import`s will **override what you imported**.

Comment: I can't think of any other way to put it. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: First remove your more-than-useless try/except blocks around the imports - you definitely *want* to know if you get any import error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

It's hard to tell what exactly is wrong, but you can:

1. Remove `from rest_apis.settings import *` from local settings.

   Your local settings should override `settings.py`, not vice versa.
2. Make sure that your imports are correct.

   Remove try/except and check if `ImportError` is raised.
3. Place your imports at the end of `settings.py`.

   Thus imported settings will override existing.

> Also, what is the correct way for this type of situation?

I think that using one local settings file for each environment (that's why it is called *local*) would be a more elegant solution:

1. Create a template for local settings, e.g. `local_settings.template.py`:

   ```
   """
   Local Django settings template.

   Usage:
       1. Copy ``local_settings.template.py`` to ``local_settings.py``.
       2. Modify ``local_settings.py`` according to your needs.

   Note that settings from ``local_settings.py``
   will override any existing Django settings.
   """

   SECRET_KEY = ''

   ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
           'HOST': '',
           'PORT': '',
           'NAME': '',
           'USER': '',
           'PASSWORD': ''
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add `local_settings.template.py` to your VCS.
3. Add `local_settings.py` to your VCS ignore.
4. Modify `settings.py`:

   ```
   """
   Core Django settings.

   Consider using local settings (see ``local_settings.template.py``)
   for environment specific Django settings and sensitive data.
   All involved settings, however, should be listed
   here with their default values and description.

   For more information on this file, visit
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

   For the full list of settings and their values, visit
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
   """

   # Settings here.

   # WARNING: local settings import should remain at the end of this file.
   try:
       from local_settings import *
   except ImportError:
       pass
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use different environments as suggested in other answers, though I recommend using separate settings files for different working environments.
The ideal project layout would be something like -

```
 project_folder -

         settings -

                    __init__.py
                    common.py
                    development.py
                    staging.py
                    production.py
                    test.py
                    main.py
```

Common staging file needs to contain all settings common to all environments. All settings file import from 'common.py'

main.py import all settings from staging.py in staging environment, development.py in development environment and production.py in production environment.

Thus, main.py would be the main settings file which needs to added to DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. As main.py is different for different environments, it should be excluded from git.

Sample Code:-

common.py

```
# All common configurations
```

development.py

```
from .common import *

# Add settings for different connections like db, cache, smtp etc.
```

production.py

```
from .common import *

# Add connection settings for production environment
```

main.py # In development environment

```
from .development import *

try:
    from local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

main.py # In staging environment

```
 from .staging import *

 try:
    from local import *
 except ImportError:
    pass
```

main.py # In production environment

```
from .production import *

try:
    from local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    settings_file = 'project_folder.settings.test' if 'test' in sys.argv else 'project_folder.settings.main'
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", settings_file)

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that settings file is assuming that all your additional settings are inside `PYTHONPATH`. If they're just inside same (sub)module as your main settings file is, use relative import like this:

```
server_environment = os.environ.get('XYZ_ENV')

if server_environment == 'staging':
    try:
        from rest_apis.settings_staging import *
    except ImportError:
        pass
elif server_environment == 'production':
    try:
        from .settings_production import *
    except ImportError:
        pass
elif server_environment == 'localserver':
    try:
        from .settings_local import *
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

Secondly, that imports should be at the end of your settings file (unless you want to have some settings that can't be ovveriden. In that case, put them below your imports).

And last but not least, make sure that your importing succeeds. Remove try - except blocks, leaving only import in your file. You can also remove conditions, just import one file to test if it's working.